# google maps iframe doesn't load multiple times in internet explorer 8

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

For some reason, Internet Explorer 8 displays only the first map in the carousel on this page:

http://www.usatruckorientation.com/

I used Bootstrap function for a carousel and just iframed a map.

Answer (score 1):

I did some googling on this one and it's an easy fix actually. If you have two or more iframe elements in your code, you need to use javascript to reload the ones *after* the first one in the code on each click of the carousel's buttons. Something like this:

```
$('.btn-back').click(function () {
  $('#FrameId').attr("src", $('#FrameId').attr("src"));
});
$('.btn-back').click(function () {
  $('#FrameId2').attr("src", $('#FrameId2').attr("src"));
});
$('.btn-fw').click(function () {
  $('#FrameId').attr("src", $('#FrameId').attr("src"));
});
$('.btn-fw').click(function () {
  $('#FrameId2').attr("src", $('#FrameId2').attr("src"));
});
```

If your carousel's buttons have classes of "btn-back" and "btn-fw", and if your second and third iframe elements have ids of "FrameId" and "FrameId2"